# How to confirm SSR-rendered HTML

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3

In Nuxt 3, you can confirm whether server-side rendering has completed with the following code, but is it possible to obtain the HTML generated after rendering has finished? I would like to check the state before client-side rendering takes place.

```
const app = useNuxtApp();
app.hook('app:rendered', () => {
  console.log('app:rendered');
});
```

I looked at the following page but couldn't find what I was looking for. If anyone knows the method, I would appreciate it if you could let me know.

https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-nuxt-app

https://nuxt.com/docs/api/advanced/hooks

Answer (score 0):

app:beforeMount is what you are looking for. It works on client side and it is the first part on client side before every things.
There are several hook points:

```
1.app:created 
2.app:rendered 
3.app:beforeMount 
4.app:mounted
```

"app:mounted" is when all thing ready to send to browser.

```
const app = useNuxtApp();
app.hook('app:rendered or what hook you want', () => {
  console.log('app:rendered or what hook you want');
});
```

### this above you can just use in `app.vue` file in the main root. Otherwise either you should write a pluging or define the hook in your nuxt.config.ts file.

I prepare a code that works in plugin. because it is better and cleaner, in my opinion.
you should make a file and folder if not exist in the main root.

### plugings/myplugin.js

```
export default defineNuxtPlugin((NuxtApp) => {
  NuxtApp.hook('app:rendered or what hook you want', async () => {
    console.log('app:rendered or what hook you want');
  })
})
```

Then, you can use the plugin by passing it with provide, useState, or other methods to your page or component.

Comment: Thank you.
So, to pause processing at app:beforeMount and check the HTML at that point, what should I do?

Comment: Yes. There are several hook points: 1.app:created 2.app:rendered 3.app:beforeMount 4.app:mounted. They are 4 main hooks in nuxt life cycle. For pause you can use await functions, return false, for, while , ...

Comment: I tried the following, but "mounted" was logged to the browser's console without interruption:
app.hook('app:beforeMount', async () => {
  console.log('Before Mount Hook');
  // You can perform asynchronous operations here

  // If you want to pause and inspect the HTML
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 10000)); // An example of waiting for 10 seconds

  // Returning false to interrupt the hook and inspect the HTML
  return false;
});

onMounted(() => {
  console.log('mounted');
});

Comment: you should use that code in app.vue file or make plugin not directly in page or component. check out the new answer